# ReactJS dynamically iterate through object and display 4 columns

Tags: reactjs

I have an `reactjs` application and I have a `state` value `monitors` that has the following structure:

This object is a dummy object, but my object has the same structure as below:

```
[
 { "key" : "value" },
 { "key" : "value" },
 { "key" : "value" },
 { "key" : "value" },
 { "key" : "value" },
 { "key" : "value" },
 { "key" : "value" },
 { "key" : "value" },
 { "key" : "value" },
]
```

And I am using `bootstrap` `row` and `col` classes to display the values. My **requirement is as below:**

1. I want to display `4` columns of these values, so each row has `4` columns

Therefore according to the above object, I have `9` sets of data that means it is 3 rows where first two rows are with 4 each and the last row (3rd row) has only one value.

How can I do this?

I am currently doing as below but I get the same value repeated as `4` columns in the same `row`. Can someone please help me?

```
{Object.entries(this.state.monitors).map(([key, value]) => (
                    <div className="container">

                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-3">
                                <div className="card mb-3 " key={this.state.monitors.id}>
                                    <div className="card-header" style={value['overall_state'] == "OK" ? service_ok : value['overall_state'] == "Alert" ? service_alert : service_nodata}>
                                        <span><i className="fa fa-th"></i></span> {" "} {value["name"]}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <h5 className="card-title">{value['overall_state'] == "OK" ? <span><i style={{ color: "#2ce659" }} class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></span> : value['overall_state'] == "Alert" ? <span><i style={{ color: "#f24c3a" }} class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></span> : <span><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i></span>} Status - {value['overall_state'] == "OK" ? "Operational" : value['overall_state'] == "Alert" ? "Outage" : "Unknown"}</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-3">
                                <div className="card mb-3 " key={this.state.monitors.id}>
                                    <div className="card-header" style={value['overall_state'] == "OK" ? service_ok : value['overall_state'] == "Alert" ? service_alert : service_nodata}>
                                        <span><i className="fa fa-th"></i></span> {" "} {value["name"]}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <h5 className="card-title">{value['overall_state'] == "OK" ? <span><i style={{ color: "#2ce659" }} class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></span> : value['overall_state'] == "Alert" ? <span><i style={{ color: "#f24c3a" }} class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></span> : <span><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i></span>} Status - {value['overall_state'] == "OK" ? "Operational" : value['overall_state'] == "Alert" ? "Outage" : "Unknown"}</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-3">
                                <div className="card mb-3 " key={this.state.monitors.id}>
                                    <div className="card-header" style={value['overall_state'] == "OK" ? service_ok : value['overall_state'] == "Alert" ? service_alert : service_nodata}>
                                        <span><i className="fa fa-th"></i></span> {" "} {value["name"]}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <h5 className="card-title">{value['overall_state'] == "OK" ? <span><i style={{ color: "#2ce659" }} class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></span> : value['overall_state'] == "Alert" ? <span><i style={{ color: "#f24c3a" }} class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></span> : <span><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i></span>} Status - {value['overall_state'] == "OK" ? "Operational" : value['overall_state'] == "Alert" ? "Outage" : "Unknown"}</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-3">
                                <div className="card mb-3 " key={this.state.monitors.id}>
                                    <div className="card-header" style={value['overall_state'] == "OK" ? service_ok : value['overall_state'] == "Alert" ? service_alert : service_nodata}>
                                        <span><i className="fa fa-th"></i></span> {" "} {value["name"]}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <h5 className="card-title">{value['overall_state'] == "OK" ? <span><i style={{ color: "#2ce659" }} class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></span> : value['overall_state'] == "Alert" ? <span><i style={{ color: "#f24c3a" }} class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></span> : <span><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i></span>} Status - {value['overall_state'] == "OK" ? "Operational" : value['overall_state'] == "Alert" ? "Outage" : "Unknown"}</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every row has 12 virtual 1-unit columns. You use 3-unit columns so only 4 will fit in the row and then wrap and start over.

You have to simply iterate over this object (like you do right now) and render single `col-3` div for every value. Make sure to wrap this loop in `container` and `row`.

Comment: It doesn't work. It will render the objects in a one column. it is not doing 4 columns in 1 row, it does 1 column in 1 row.

Comment: I've prepared a demo for you - take a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-pond-m6y0r). Do I misunderstand your problem?